# I am getting error when i am using git hub actions to download the submodules of git

Tags: python, git, azure, action, hub

I am using the git hub actions to automate from git hub to app service to deploy but when I have to zip the two folders to deploy into app service it is not able to download the repo of submodules and I have added the PAT in the parent secrets added  tried I am getting the error with returning 128 in git hub actions and tried by adding two PAT in secrets but it is returning same error:

```
/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand

73  /usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"

74  /usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader

75  http.https://github.com/.extraheader

76  /usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader

77  /usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :"

78Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128
```

Comment: Are you trying to deploy your application to Azure App Service using GitHub actions?

Comment: Yes I am deploying the python app using git hub actions but inside the repo i am unable to download the submodule